# How to put a backslash before single quote for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, neo4j

I typed as below:

```
str = "Jane\'s very good..."
# => "Jane's very good..."

str = "Jane\\'s very good..."
# => "Jane\\'s very good..."
```

How can I get `str` with single quotes like:

```
"Jane\'s very good..."
```

I'm working with neo4j(NoSQL) architecture to social media words analysing;

```
words = txt.split(' ')
                notIncludingWords = Array.new
                sqlParameter=''
                words.each do |word|
                    if(Word.where(name:word).first.nil?)
                       notIncludingWords.push(word)
                    else
                        sqlParameter+=",'"+word+"'"
                    end
                end
                sqlParameter = sqlParameter[1..sqlParameter.length-1]
```

... (Transactions...)

```
table = Word.query_as(:w).where("w.name IN["+sqlParameter+"]")

                    RecordCount = table.return("SUM(w.recordcount) AS recordcount").first.recordcount.to_f
```

...(Transactions)

When I try ro run, it gives me an error;

```
Cypher error:
  [36mNeo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError[0m: Invalid input 'ı': expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or ']' (line 1, column 71 (offset: 70))
"MATCH (w:`Word`) WHERE (w.name IN['26','yıl','önce','bugün','Hasan'ın','doğum','günüdür']) RETURN SUM(w.recordcount) AS recordcount"
```

Comment: "Jane\\'s very good..." is, but using `puts`.

Comment: your first option solves it no?

Comment: What are you typing into that provides the `>>` prompt?

Comment: Or `'Jane\\\'s very good...'`

Comment: I will use it to database inputs. When I use this this gives me an error; table = Word.query_as(:w).where("w.name IN["+sqlParameter+"]")

Comment: Out of curiosity (because I don't know much about this sort of thing), is `Word.query_as(:w).where("w.name IN["+sqlParameter+"]")` an opportunity for SQL injection? Sorry if it's a not-smart question.

Comment: Why would you `where("w.name IN["+sqlParameter+"]")` when you could `where("w.name IN ?", sqlParameter)`? Or is `sqlParameter` a column name or other identifier?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ - Why not `Word.where(name: nameArray).sum(:recordcount)`?

Comment: I'm using neo4j for this situation it doesn't work ):

Answer (score 1):

You've got it right actually. The irb is just returning the escaped representation.

e.g.

```
>> str = "\\"
=> "\\" 

>> str.length
=> 1 

>> puts str
\
=> nil

>> puts "Jane\\'s very good..."
=> Jane\'s very good...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will use it to database inputs. When I use this this gives me an error; table = Word.query_as(:w).where("w.name IN["+sqlParameter+"]")

Comment: You might want to post a different question re ActiveNode, which I'm not familiar with. I'm guessing you need to escape the sqlParameter to make the database happy. If ActiveNode gives you string interpolation like ActiveRecord, then I think you want `Word.query_as(:w).where("w.name in (?)", [sqlParameter])`. Note: Why are you using IN when you only have one value?

Comment: I try it but it didn't. It's only the part of my code. I re-edited my post maybe you can solve it.